Number of Sylow 2-subgroups in $S_7$
I am struggling with finding the number of Sylow 2-subgroups in $S_7$. I have found the subgroups, they are isomorphic to $D_4 \times \mathbb{Z}/(2)$. The generators are, for example, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3} and {5, 6}. There are $\frac{7!}{4 \cdot 3!} = 210$ elements of the first cyclic type and $\frac{7!}{2 \cdot 5!} = 21$ elements of the second cyclic type. What is the next step?

First, count the number of copies of $S_4$ in $S_7$. I think there are $\binom{7}{4}$ of them because we permute $4$ symbols at a time. Each of these copies of $S_4$ contains three copies of $D_4$. Thus, there are $\binom 74\times 3$ copies of $D_4$ in $S_7$. Every copy of $D_4$ uses $4$ symbols at a time, leaving us with $3$ symbols and hence, there are $\binom{3}{2}$ transpositions for the $\mathbb Z/(2)$ part. Thus, $\binom 74\times 3\times \binom32$.

Got it! Thank you so much!

Why are you doing this? Is this an exercise question?

@mathemaniac post your solution then :)

I had to find all Sylow subgroups of $S_7$ and count them. So I had a problem with 2-subgroups.

The Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_7$ are isomorphic to $D_4\times \mathbb Z/(2)$ as you've determined.
First, count the number of copies of $S_4$ in $S_7$. There are $\binom 74$ of them because we permute $4$ symbols at a time. Each of these copies of $S_4$ contains three copies of $D_4$. (This is an easy exercise.)
Thus, there are $\binom 74×3$ copies of $D_4$ in $S_7$. Every copy of $D_4$ uses $4$ symbols at a time, leaving us with $3$ symbols to spare and hence, there are $\binom 32$ transpositions for generating the $\mathbb Z/(2)$ part.
Thus, the total count of $\binom74×3×\binom32=315$ Sylow $2$-subgroups.
